# Cannot change dbPath for mongod

Tags: windows, mongodb

I am trying to set up MongoDB v4.2.2 on Windows 10.

Whenever I run mongod, I am unable to change the dbPath, no matter what I do. It keeps defaulting to `F:/MongoDB`, every single time.

This is the logs from running any form of the `mongod` command:

```
2019-12-29T22:40:28.438-0800 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=9860 port=27017 dbpath=F:/MongoDB 64-bit host=DESKTOP-5CA5F06
2019-12-29T22:40:28.438-0800 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] targetMinOS: Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 R2
2019-12-29T22:40:28.438-0800 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.2.2
2019-12-29T22:40:28.438-0800 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: a0bbbff6ada159e19298d37946ac8dc4b497eadf
2019-12-29T22:40:28.438-0800 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2019-12-29T22:40:28.438-0800 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2019-12-29T22:40:28.438-0800 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2019-12-29T22:40:28.438-0800 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: 2012plus
2019-12-29T22:40:28.438-0800 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2019-12-29T22:40:28.439-0800 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2019-12-29T22:40:28.439-0800 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { storage: { dbPath: "F:/MongoDB" } }
2019-12-29T22:40:28.440-0800 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: NonExistentPath: Data directory F:/2019-12-29T22:40:28.440-0800 I  NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2019-12-29T22:40:28.440-0800 I  -        [initandlisten] Stopping further Flow Control ticket acquisitions.
2019-12-29T22:40:28.440-0800 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2019-12-29T22:40:28.441-0800 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100
```

I first tried running `mongod -dbpath C:/mongo-data/testdb`, and got the above result.

I then tried `mongod -dbpath "C:/mongo-data/testdb`, to the same result.

Then I changedthe `mongod.cfg` file in `C:/Program Files/MongoDB/Server/4.2/bin` to be the following:

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: "C:\mongo-data\testdb"
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path:  %MONGO_LOG_PATH%\mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1


#processManagement:

#security:

#operationProfiling:

#replication:

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

and then ran `mongod`, followed by the two commands above once more. Each time, I got the same exact result I posted above.

I also tried removing the quotes around the value for dbPath in the config, and running each command again to the same result.

How on earth do I get mongod to stop looking for this `F:/MongoDB` directory that doesn't exist?

Comment: Also, make sure the directory `C:\mongo-data\testdb` exists.

Answer (score 0):

Please give it a try with `mongod --dbpath "C:/mongo-data/testdb"`.

Change here is, the dbpath comes with '--' instead of a single one.

Comment: Unfortunately, did not work. Same result as last time. This is the exact command I tried: `PS C:\Users\Logan> mongod --dbpath "C:/mongo-data/testdb"`

Comment: is mongo installed with chocolatey, service or running with mongo binaries?

Comment: No, I installed it from the installer on Mongo's website, and had it run not as a service. Would installing it as a service potentially fix the issue?

Comment: It should work ideally well with binaries as well since I have used it with binaries and as a service as well. But then installing as a service will give you a configuration file to maintain in a single place and will be definitely of help.